# Why do I see a seg fault in this?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class student
{
    public:
    string s;
    int age;
};

ostream& operator<<( ostream &output,const student &s) 
{
      output << s.s << " " << s.age << "\n";
      return output;

}

istream& operator >>(istream& in, student& val) 
{
    return in >> val.s >> val.age;
}


bool valuecmp(const student & a, const student & b)
{
    return a.s < b.s;
}

int main (void)
{
    vector<student> a;
    student b;
    cin>>b.s;
    cin>>b.age;
    fstream myfile; 
    myfile.open("a1.txt",ios::app);
    int i = 0;
    myfile << b;
    cout<<"File has been written"<<"\n";
    myfile.open("a1.txt",ios::in);
    for (string line; getline(myfile, line);) 
    {
        istringstream stream(line);
        student person;
        stream >> person;
        a.push_back(person);
        cout<<a[i].s<<a[i].age<<"\n";
        i++;
    }
    sort(a.begin(),a.end(),valuecmp);
    fstream my;
    my.open("a2.txt",ios::out);
    student c;
    for ( i = 0; i < 2; i++ )
    {
        cout<<a[i].s<<a[i].age<<"\n";
        c = a[i];
        my << c;
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

A simple program to accept user input, store in an object. I have multiple inputs already in the file before running this program. So, when I made this program to accept the input from the user, write in a file, and then sort the contents of the entire file, using, the sort operation and then write the sorted output in a new file.

This accepts user input, shows the message, `File has been written`, but then shows a seg fault. Why is it happening?

Comment: Well, have you run the code through the debugger to see what exactly is throwing the exception?

Comment: You're not closing the file after you've written to it then try to reopen it. Close the file and add some error checking.

Comment: Why does your final loop ignore the size of a?

Comment: I put it there deliberately just to see if its working or not.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious, can you elaborate on it? Thanks!

Comment: @CaptainObvlious, true you were. I

Comment: Maybe your segfault is telling you `a` is empty. This would be easier to diagnose if you checked for errors anywhere, or tried a debugger.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting a segfault on this line

```
 cout<<a[i].s<<a[i].age<<"\n";
```

because `a` is empty when you try to access it.  `a.push_back(person)` never gets called so no data is added to your vector.  `getline()` fails the first time.

Hope this leads you in a helpful direction.